# Is there an example of how to add Replace to Google Docs

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there an example anywhere of how to use the Document apps-script API to add a button to the Google Docs menu, when it is clicked bring up a web page from my web app that prompts the user for 2 strings, then on OK it does a search & replace on the open document?

I don't need to add search/replace per-se. I just figure this is the simplest example of writing an Add-In to Google Docs that edits the open document.

thanks - dave

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it stands, this is not possible. I think [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=721&q=add%20menu%20docs&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner) (which you might like to star so that you can receive updates in the thread) best describes it. Summary in post #7:

> This feature request is to add the same script functionality to a
>   document as there is in a spreadsheet. ie menu items etc.

Answer (score 2):

A recent video by google (see their blogs) hints that this will be soon available.
In the meantime u can ask for the document url from your published script interface.
If you make a googledrive.com client app you can even use the new goglepicker to select the doc.